# How do I Install R Github packages inside Docker

Tags: r, docker, github, google-analytics, devtools

I am trying to create a Docker image for my R script to schedule the R job on Google Cloud. I am currently testing it with a small R Script. The `docker build` commands fails at the step where I am installing the `rga` GitHub package. Below is my R script and the DockerFile:

R script:

```
library(rga)
library(bigrquery)
bq_token()
rga.open(instance = "ga", where="~/ga.rga")

demoScheduleAPI <- function(){
  search_perf <- ga$getData(XXXX, batch = TRUE, walk = TRUE, 
                          start.date = "2020-01-15",
                          end.date = "2020-01-16",
                          metrics = "ga:searchUniques",
                          dimensions="ga:date,ga:hour,ga:searchKeyword, ga:searchCategory ,ga:dimension6,ga:dimension10")
  project <- "bidone-data"
  insert_upload_job(project, "GA_Export_Prod_DataSet", "Test_Table123", search_perf)
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.6.1

RUN mkdir /home/bidone

RUN R -e "install.packages('bigrquery', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

RUN R -e "install.packages('devtools', repos='http://cloud.r-project.org')"

RUN R -e "devtools::install_github('skardhamar/rga')"

COPY .secrets /home/analysis/.secrets

COPY ga /home/analysis/ga

COPY DockerTest.R /home/analysis/DOckerTest.R

CMD R -e "source('/home/analysis/DockerTest.R')"
```

It does install devtools package, however when it tries to install the `rga` package from github, it gives the following error.

```
> devtools::install_github('skardhamar/rga')
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘devtools’
Calls: :: ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
The command '/bin/sh -c R -e "devtools::install_github('skardhamar/rga')"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 6):

*Edit in Sep 2023:* These days one *really* wants to use [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) as the basis for your container.  I have by now added a few other answers at StackOverflow describing use of [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) so one can search for those.

---

Your best bet for these things are GitHub searches.  Here is one example of mine for a container used to support a [class I teach](https://stat430.com), building on [another Dockerfile from our Rocker Project](https://github.com/stat430dspm/rocker-pl/blob/master/Dockerfile).  The link gives you the full details, but omitting bits for brevity here we have

```
FROM rocker/r-ubuntu:18.04   

# Install required libraries -- using prebuild binaries where available
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    r-cran-data.table \
    r-cran-devtools \
    r-cran-doparallel \
    r-cran-dygraphs \
    r-cran-foreach \
    r-cran-fs \
    r-cran-future.apply \
    r-cran-gh \
    r-cran-git2r \
    r-cran-igraph \
    r-cran-memoise \
    r-cran-microbenchmark \
    r-cran-png \
    r-cran-rcpparmadillo \
    r-cran-rex \
    r-cran-rsqlite \
    r-cran-runit \
    r-cran-shiny \
    r-cran-stringdist \
    r-cran-testthat \
    r-cran-tidyverse \
    r-cran-tinytest \
    r-cran-xts \
    sqlite3 \
    sudo

# Install additional R packages from CRAN (on top of the ones 
# pre-built as r-cran-*)
RUN install.r bench diffobj flexdashboard lintr ttdo unix

# Install plr -- for now (?) from GH; also install visualTest
RUN installGithub.r stat430dspm/plr MangoTheCat/visualTest
```

That pretty much covers it as we

- use the PPA by Michael Rutter to get as much as we can for Ubuntu LTS (currently still 18.04) via prebuild .deb packages for Ubuntu
- use the [littler](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler) script `install.r` to install some packages from CRAN
- use another [littler](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler) script `installGithub.r` to install two more repos from GitHub

That just shows my preferred rank-ordering: binaries over CRAN over GitHub.  The key point for your question is that these [littler](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler) scripts are also on the R-ver stack for Rocker.  But with r-ver you have to *very careful* about mixing as the release date is fixed with MRAN *by design*.

(And in case anybody wants to know more about the *why* of *this* container, we just put a [pre-print on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.11144) -- but this is pretty specific to the testing and grading infrastructure we use.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am going to try that,, but i believe that this will install ubuntu env within the docker. I am not used to ubuntu. I was wondering if you could help me verify if the copy and run commands would be same in ubuntu

Comment: I tried to make this clear in my answer. You can also ignore that part. "If you're patient" you can install all from source -- focus on `install.r` for CRAN, and `installGithub.r` for GitHub.  The rest is an illustration :)

Comment: Your narrower question about the interdependence of the one package you are trying to install can, I fear, only be answered by inspecting that one package. In essence, you are already doing what I am doing (with more verbose commands / more separate RUN commands which is not ideal but of course totally valid...).

Comment: I get what you are trying to say. I guess I am gonna try installing all the dependencies first with R-ver and then try to install other packages as you pointed out and will see if that helps. Guess it all comes down to patience while installation :)

Comment: Right. And I like binaries to make it quicker. You could even build as I have showm (all binaries) to iron out the one GitHub repo you are after, and once you have that squared maybe pivot back to r-ver is that is what you want.  Many routes.

Comment: Well I am not that proficient in docker yet and still trying to learn and follow instructions. I tried installing all the required libraries and I yet again get the error `Package r-cran-devtools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'r-cran-devtools' has no installation candidate` So Not sure whats going on here. Anything you can suggest

Comment: Drill down one level, look eg [here at Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/r-cran-devtools). I often also fire up a base container of the variant you are using -- in my case Ubuntu 18.04 (though with added Rocker layers), then do `apt-get update` and `apt-cache search`.  You can only install what is there -- so you need little familiarity with the binary packaging system.  Else ... the alternative is to be _very_ patient and install all from CRAN.  I generally prefer binaries though.

Comment: Lastly, for the broader questions, we have a mailing list [r-sig-debian](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-debian) for 'R on Debian or Ubuntu' questions.  Ask there for specific questions on "how do I find a package xyz" etc.  Good luck!

Comment: I tried to replicate exactly what you have up there, it works... Looks like the issue is with the rga package that I am trying to install

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried to say earlier (3rd comment).  You have the installation mechanics down (i.e. you didn't even need this question). "Merely" debugging one particular package.